# New disclaimer from google

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Today we have met with this problem -

[image]

"Google Experts have not reviewed this app
The application requests access to sensitive information in your Google account. We do not recommend that you use this application until it has been verified by Google (developer: angel.group1234@gmail.com).
"

What I need to do? Is that new update from Google?

Comment: See their docs → https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914

Answer (score 0):

An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.

While your application is in development you can just click the link on the bottom to ignore this and continue to use the unsafe app.

Once you have completed development of your application you can then apply for verification to remove this message.

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
- [How I fixed Google hasn’t verified this app!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6935WKdaH6E)

Btw this isnt new its been around for a few years at least.